# FlutterEngineGroup makeEngine return nil when doesn't execute with Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

Now I'm trying to connect Flutter project with existent iOS project.
Connect with Pod, import is also well.

```swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FlutterPluginRegistrant

@main
class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    
    private let lifecycleDelegate = FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate()
    let flutterGroup: FlutterEngineGroup = .init(name: "chat_module", project: nil)
    private(set) var loginEngine: FlutterEngine?
    private(set) var aiEngine: FlutterEngine?
    
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        PushLocationManager.shared.configureFirebase()
        
        loginEngine = flutterGroup.makeEngine(withEntrypoint: nil, libraryURI: nil, initialRoute: "/login")
        aiEngine = flutterGroup.makeEngine(withEntrypoint: nil, libraryURI: nil, initialRoute: "/ai")
        
        guard let loginEngine, let aiEngine else {
            return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        }
        
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: loginEngine)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: aiEngine)
        
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
}
```

This logic drives well, when execute project from Xcode run. I can move to FlutterView, but when execute this app not use Xcode(in device, tap the appIcone to execute) FlutterEngineGroup.makeEngine return nil.

I tried to make FlutterViewController using .init(project:, initialRoute:, nibName:, bundle:), when engine is nil. But it makes fatalError.
Why flutter connect logic is executed well, when run with only Xcode.